# Deadlock at findAll

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-jpa

Возникла проблема с реализацией методов findAll(). При вызове возникает Deadlock.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
   /** id и другие поля **/
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Faculty faculty;
 }

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "faculties")
public class Faculty {
   /** id и другие поля **/
   @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Реализация репозиториев:

```
@Repository
public interface FacultyRepository extends JpaRepository<Faculty, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {
}
```

Когда из контроллера вызываю метод findAll() - результат следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данный Deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
   /** id и другие поля **/
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_faculty")
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
   private Faculty faculty;
 }

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "faculties")
public class Faculty {
   /** id и другие поля **/
   //@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) - это удаляем
   //private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>(); - это так-же удаляем

}
```

Comment: Это ответ, это решает вашу проблему?

Comment: так точно)
очень помогла статья - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/